# Writing to a new default library in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the BiocManager for FLOWSOM (a plugin for FlowJo), and I'm unable to write to the default library located in Program Files. I added a new path called C:\R\Library and used .libPaths to add it to my library list. However, when I try to install packages, R still attempts to write to the old library and encounters an error.

Thanks!

```
libPaths("C:/R/Library")
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/R/Library"                       "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/library"
> if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
+     install.packages("BiocManager")
Bioconductor version 3.16 (BiocManager 1.30.19), R 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
> BiocManager::install(version = "3.16")
Bioconductor version 3.16 (BiocManager 1.30.19), R 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Installation paths not writeable, unable to update packages
  path: C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/library
Warning: package 'boot' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'Matrix' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/library' will not be updated
```

This is what I see when I attempt to install the BiocManager after adding my new Library. Why can't I overwrite the old library, or delete it? I've changed the R_LIB_USER located in the control panel to my new library, however that didn't change anything.

I've also attempted to install the BiocManager only to the new library by adding it to the installation code

```
> if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
+install.packages("BiocManager", "C:/R/Library")
> BiocManager::install(version = "3.16")
```

but I still get this error message:

```
Bioconductor version 3.16 (BiocManager 1.30.19), R 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Installation paths not writeable, unable to update packages
  path: C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/library
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I permanently change the installation path so that I don't encounter this problem anymore

Comment: Try  `BiocManager::install(version = "3.16", lib="C:/R/Library")`

Comment: Did you restart R after editing `R_LIB_USER`.